# Python print two lists with string format operator

Tags: python

How do I write python scrip to solve this?

```
l=[1,2,3] Length A
X=[one,two,three,.... ] length A
```

how do print/write to file
output should be

```
1=one 2=two 3=three ....
```

Trying to use something like but since the Length A is variable this won't work

```
logfile.write('%d=%s %d=%s %d=%s %d=%s \n' % (l[1], X[1],l[2,X[3],l[4],X[4]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip`:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
X = ['one', 'two', 'three']
' '.join('{}={}'.format(first, second) for first, second in zip(l, X))
```

Output:

```
'1=one 2=two 3=three'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an fString to make this more concise:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
strings = ['one', 'two', 'three']
print(' '.join(f'{n}={s}' for n,s in zip(numbers,strings)))
```

Answer (score 0):

- zip(a, b) would return pairs from both lists until shorter list is over
- map(f, a) would apply function f to every element in list a.
- join is a python way to concatenate strings

All combined:

```
print(''.join(map('{}={}'.format, zip(l, X))))
print(''.join(map('='.join, zip(map(str,l), X))))
```

since join works on strings only, map(str,l) convert [1, 2,..] to ['1', '2', ..]

format works on any input, so extra conversion is not required